# How do I create custom Interface Builder plugins for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I'm just getting started with iPhone development, and I'd like to be able to create custom user interface elements that you can drag-and-drop into the application in Interface Builder.  How do you create custom plugins like this for Interface Builder for the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Interface Builder plugins are not (yet?) supported for iPhone OS, so what you want is not possible at the moment. You can instantiate custom objects from IB by placing a plain UIView in your interface and setting its class to your custom control's class. But all the user would see in IB would be an empty rectangle and all customization would have to be done in code.